# Linq help with OrderBy

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Hi I use Linq and EF 4.

I have this query, but it seems not able to order the result by a string variable `sortExpression`.
I suppose I'm doing smt wrong in `"it."` part.
Notes: `sortExpression` could have like `Title`

Could you please have a look and tell me what is wrong in my syntax? Thanks for your help

```
               var myContentsForAuthor = from c in context.CmsContents
                                          join a in context.CmsAuthors on c.AuthorId equals a.AuthorId
                                          join u in context.aspnet_Users on a.UserId equals u.UserId
                                          orderby("it." + sortExpression)
                                          where u.UserId == myUserGuid && c.IsDeleted == false && c.Title.Contains(nameSearchString)
                                          select c;
                return myContentsForAuthor.ToList();
```

Comment: where does "it." comes from ? i only see c,a and u

Comment: for IT i mean c properties. ex: c.Tile or c.Description.

Answer (score 1):

You can acheive what you want like the following:

```
var myContentsForAuthor = from c in context.CmsContents
                          join a in context.CmsAuthors on c.AuthorId equals a.AuthorId
                          join u in context.aspnet_Users on a.UserId equals u.UserId
                          where u.UserId == myUserGuid && c.IsDeleted == false && c.Title.Contains(nameSearchString)
                          select c;
if(sortExpression == 'Title')
{
  return myContentsForAuthor.Where(c => c.Title).ToList();
}

if(sortExpression == 'Author')
{
  return myContentsForAuthor.Where(c => c.Author.Name).ToList();
}
```

**NOTE: Always put `orderby` at the end of your queries.**

EDIT: I updated the code
EDIT2: updated it to be more simpler

Answer (score 0):

`orderby` requires to specify member. in your case - `orderby c(?).Titile` and not `ordeby(string)`. It seems that you have to use expression trees (dynamic LINQ) to create needed query.

Comment: are you able to give me an example of dynamic LINQ query for my case?

Comment: take a look to http://www.singingeels.com/Blogs/Nullable/2008/03/26/Dynamic_LINQ_OrderBy_using_String_Names.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct a dynamic linq query. See the answers to this question [How can I do an OrderBy with a dynamic string parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728340/linq-orderby-with-dynamic-string-parameter).