# Order Linq Join

Tags: c#, linq

i try any thing you sayed but i cant do my job 
its my code

```
    Func<Dead, Object> orderByFunc = null;
    orderByFunc = Dead => Dead.Last_Name;
    var query = from ded in searchDead
                    join ask in Asker on ded.Family_Number equals ask.Family_Number
                    orderby orderByFunc
                    select ask;
    Functions.searchAsker = query.AsQueryable<Asker>();
```

Comment: What *exactly* have you tried and in what way did it not work for you? By not specifying, you're leaving yourself open to receiving the same suggestions again, which wastes everyone's time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I do an OrderBy with a dynamic string parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728340/how-can-i-do-an-orderby-with-a-dynamic-string-parameter)

Comment: i want to create order fild by string

Comment: @JonSkeet - I'm assuming he'd like `...orderby("Last_Name")`

Comment: string order = "Last_Name";

Comment: @DeeMac: Yes, but that doesn't give us any indication of what has already been tried or what the result was.

Comment: no this samples not work cause of i select table ask only work when use (ded.Last_Name)

Comment: i tried like this                  orderFild = "Last_Name";
                var query = from ded in Functions.searchDead
                            join ask in dataBase.Asker on ded.Family_Number equals ask.Family_Number
                            orderby (orderFild)
                            select ask;

Comment: and `orderFild = "ded.Last_Name";
                var query = from ded in Functions.searchDead
                            join ask in dataBase.Asker on ded.Family_Number equals ask.Family_Number
                            orderby (orderFild)
                            select ask;`

Comment: thanks any way but i dont find my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
string order = "Last Name";
var propertyorder = null
switch (order)
{
    case "Last Name":
        propertyorder = ded.Last_Name;
        break;
    case "First Name":
        propertyorder = ded.First_Name
        break;
    default:
        propertyorder = ded.Last_Name;
        break;
}

   var query = from ded in Dead
    join ask in Asker on ded.Family_Number equals ask.Family_Number
    orderby (propertyorder)
    select ask;
```