# How can I order a column in Linq where that column is a string?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an index which from a dictionary get the column string to order by in Linq

```
dict.Add(0, "seleccionado");
dict.Add(1, "IdPedido");
dict.Add(2, "FechaPedido");
dict.Add(3, "NSerie");
dict.Add(4, "Importe");
```

I have, too,  a list of Orders and I need to get the order (DESC/ASC) when I click in the column of the field.

Mmy idea was to do the Linq in one line because I will pass two parameters: the string field to order and the direction (ASC/DESC).

How can I do it in Linq?

**WHAT I TRIED:**

```
pedidos.OrderBy(x => x.seleccionado);
```

seleccionado is the object of the class, but in my case I will give an string instead of the object field name.

Comment: I answered in the same question

Comment: Did you search before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question, you're asking how to sort a collection by a field, where the field is chosen by the user.

In this case, why not store the lambda in the dictionary?

```
dict.Add(0, x => x.seleccionado);
dict.Add(1, x => x.IdPedido);

// etc.
```

Comment: What if property types are different?

Comment: Prperties are dates, int and bool

Comment: @L.B, then store an IComparer there instead.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe I am not looking for an answer, I criticized your answer.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2728432/3825634

This has been answered before.

There are dynamic linq libraries available. They will allow you to build up parts of your linq queries dynamically with strings.

Comment: Is it standard with VS2010?