# How can I do an OrderBy with a dynamic string parameter order on a join query

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, join, sql-order-by

I want to do this:

```
var test = SqlCompact("OrderID", "ASC")
```

So this should sort the following join query by order ID:

```
var result = (from od in orders
        join em in employees on od.EmployeeID equals em.EmployeeID
        join ct in customers on od.CustomerID equals ct.CustomerID
        //orderby em.EmployeeID
        select new
        {
            od.OrderID,
            od.ShipCountry,
            ct.CompanyName,
            ct.ContactName,
            FullName = em.FirstName + ' '+ em.LastName, 
        }).ToList();
```

My attempt:

```
var result2 = result.ToList();
if (sort == "OrderID"){
 result2 = result.OrderBy("OrderID");
}
```

But I get the error:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicQueryable.OrderBy(System.Linq.IQueryable, string, params object[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: `result.OrderBy(x=>x.OrderID);`  ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do an OrderBy with a dynamic string parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728340/how-can-i-do-an-orderby-with-a-dynamic-string-parameter)

Comment: @DarkKnight, I did try that before but I got this error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>'

Comment: @user3521029 :  `result.OrderBy(x=>x.OrderID).ToList()`  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
var result2 = result.ToList();
if (sort == "OrderID"){
 result2 = result.OrderBy(x=>x.OrderID).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Then I get an error with returning result2. For `return result2;`. I get the following error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<UserQuery.MyJoin>'

Comment: @user3521029 : at which line?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to write my whole SqlCompact function. But basically I want to return result2 to the main method. That's where I get that error.

Comment: @user3521029 : please add function code. Ensure your return type of the function and result2's datatype match. If not, cast it.