# A replacement for OrderBy Switch in C#

Tags: c#, list, switch-statement, sql-order-by

The following code snippet works fine.

```
switch (sortOrder)
{
    case "Group":
        list = list.OrderBy(o => o.Group).ToList();
        break;
    case "Company":
        list = list.OrderBy(o => o.Company).ToList();
        break;
    case "CurrencyId":
        list = list.OrderBy(o => o.CurrencyId).ToList();
        break;
    case "Field":
        list = list.OrderBy(o => o.Field).ToList();
        break; 
}
```

But i would like to write a more flexable code, not using a switch at all. Something like:

```
list = list.OrderBy(o => o.sortOrder).ToList();
```

How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728340/how-can-i-do-an-orderby-with-a-dynamic-string-parameter

Comment: this is the best way actually. you can do it with reflection but i dont suggest you to do it. try to write efficient code instead of simplifying everything.

Answer (score 4):

Using reflection is one alternative:

```
var sortOrder = "Group";

list = list.OrderBy(o => o.GetType().GetProperty(sortOrder).GetValue(o)).ToList();
```

Note that if you set "sortOrder" to a property name that doesn't actually exist in the class, you'll get a `NullReferenceException`. But if you're in control of the value, and not just accepting what a user types in (for example), then it'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use reflection. The problem is that reflection is slow and ugly.

```
list.OrderBy(o => o.GetType().GetProperty(sortOrder).GetValue(o)).ToList()
```

There's not much you can do about the performance. To make it look nicer you could put it into an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrderByPropertyName<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string propertyName)
{
    var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);

    if (property == null) return source; // or throw exception
    else return source.OrderBy(x => property.GetValue(x));
}
```

Then use it as

```
list.OrderByPropertyName(sortOrder)
```

It works slightly faster than the first reflection approach, because `GetProperty` is only called once. You can also control the behavior if the property doesn't exist.

In my opinion, int this case `switch` is better than reflection.

Comment: I used you answers slightly modified in a related Question. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74703425/6560478). Feel free to edit attribution if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of @Jakub Lortz is quite good however there is more universal one.

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderByPropertyName<T>(
    this IQueryable<T>source,
    string propertyName)
where T: YourClass
{
    // Here better to throw some exception
    if (propertyName == null) return source; 
    var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);

    return source.OrderBy(x => property.GetValue(x));
}
```