# linq orderby using property name string

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a list which I need to order eg.

```
var list = someelements;
```

I also have a parameter which says by which property and what direction I should order list data eg.

```
var sortby = "Name";
var sortdirection = "desc";
```

I was wondering if I can match string property name with the right property so I get:

```
var list = someelements.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

when `sortby == "Name"` without the need of using switch loop to check property name and assign a correct property to OrderBy.

Same I would like to achieve with select either `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` depending whether I get `sortdirection = "asc"` or `sortdirection = "desc"`

Is it possible and if yes, how?

Comment: Relying on `OrderBy` or on `OrderByDescending` on acount of the `sortDirection` values is quite straightforward: use a condition (even a ternary operator would do the job in this situation).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do an OrderBy with a dynamic string parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728340/how-can-i-do-an-orderby-with-a-dynamic-string-parameter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get `Dynamic Linq` through Nuget. Then you can use `.OrderBy(sortby + " " + sortdirection)`.
Here is the link: [Dynamic Linq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I used the port of this library for .net core:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core

Answer (score 7):

Here is one solution that does not use Dynamic Linq:

```
public class Helper
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> OrderByDynamic<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, string sortby, string sort_direction)
    {
        var property = typeof (T).GetProperty(sortby);

        var result = typeof(Helper)
            .GetMethod("OrderByDynamic_Private", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
            .MakeGenericMethod(typeof (T), property.PropertyType)
            .Invoke(null, new object[]{ items, sortby, sort_direction});

        return (IEnumerable<T>)result;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> OrderByDynamic_Private<T,TKey>(IEnumerable<T> items, string sortby, string sort_direction)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T), "x");

        Expression<Func<T, TKey>> property_access_expression =
            Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TKey>>(
                Expression.Property(parameter, sortby),
                parameter);

        if (sort_direction == "asc")
        {
            return items.OrderBy(property_access_expression.Compile());
        }

        if (sort_direction == "desc")
        {
            return items.OrderByDescending(property_access_expression.Compile());
        }

        throw new Exception("Invalid Sort Direction");
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var result = Helper.OrderByDynamic(list, "Name", "desc").ToList();
```