# Return Func<IQueryable<Level>, IOrderedQueryable<Level>> where sort by property found in runtime

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, lambda, expression

I have the below method. It returns expression which is called by my repository Get method

```
  public Func<IQueryable<Level>, IOrderedQueryable<Level>> GetOrderByExpression()
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            request = new OrderByRequest
            {
                IsAscending = true,  PropertyName = "Name"  // CreatedDate , LevelNo etc
            };
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.PropertyName))
        {
            request.PropertyName = "Name";
        }
        Type entityType = typeof(Level);
        ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "x");
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = entityType.GetProperty(request.PropertyName);
        Expression<Func<Level, object>> sortExpression =
            Expression.Lambda<Func<Level, object>>(
                Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(parameterExpression, request.PropertyName),
                    Type.GetType(propertyInfo.PropertyType.FullName)), parameterExpression);

        Func<IQueryable<Level>, IOrderedQueryable<Level>> expression = request.IsAscending
            ? (Func<IQueryable<Level>, IOrderedQueryable<Level>>)(x => x.OrderBy(sortExpression))
            : (x => x.OrderByDescending(sortExpression));
        return expression;
    }
```

Repository is calling like below (removed unnecessary codes for clarity):

```
public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> Get(
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null)
{
     var query = DbContext.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
      if (orderBy != null)
                {
                    query = orderBy(query);
                }
}
```

The above method is working perfectly for string type of properties of Level class. But for the other types (like Integer/DateTime etc) it is not working and throwing error

> Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type
>   'System.Object'

***I want to make this method a generic OrderByExpression provider, and it will take the property names at runtime (this name will come from client side), so
   that it can work with any property of that given object. Is it possible?***

Comment: For the sake of testing, replace `Func<Level, object>`  with `Func<Level, int>` and test it for a property of type `int`. If it works, then you can create a solution similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34003282/2290059). The idea of that answer is to create a generic method like `GetOrderByExpression<TProperty>()` that uses `Func<Level, TProperty>` instead of `Func<Level, object>` and make your original method call this new method via reflection, passing in the correct property type as `TProperty`.

Comment: You can have `orderby` that accepts property names, see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955025/generate-ef-orderby-expression-by-string/31959568#31959568

Comment: Thanks Taher. I have gone through your (and many other's) answers yesterday. I want a Func from the method, but your provided answer is returning Ordered list. This is the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of `OrderBy` is as follows

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source,
    Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector
)
```

As you see, there is a second generic argument `TKey` which when the selector represents a property is the type of the property. The problem with your code is that you assume that every property can be represented by `Func<TSource, object>` which in general is incorrect.

Here is a generic function that does correctly what you are trying to accomplish

```
public static class QueryableUtils
{
    public static Func<IQueryable<TSource>, IOrderedQueryable<TSource>> OrderByFunc<TSource>(string propertyName, bool ascending = true)
    {
        var source = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IQueryable<TSource>), "source");
        var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "item");
        var member = Expression.Property(item, propertyName);
        var selector = Expression.Quote(Expression.Lambda(member, item));
        var body = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable), ascending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending",
            new Type[] { item.Type, member.Type },
            source, selector);
        var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<IQueryable<TSource>, IOrderedQueryable<TSource>>>(body, source);
        var func = expr.Compile();
        return func;
    }
}
```

Using it in your case would be something like this

```
public Func<IQueryable<Level>, IOrderedQueryable<Level>> GetOrderByExpression()
{
    if (request == null)
    {
        request = new OrderByRequest
        {
            IsAscending = true,  PropertyName = "Name"  // CreatedDate , LevelNo etc
        };
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.PropertyName))
    {
        request.PropertyName = "Name";
    }
    return QueryableUtils.OrderByFunc<Level>(request.PropertyName, request.IsAscending);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative way.

```
public  Func<IQueryable<Level>, IOrderedQueryable<Level>> GetOrderByFunc()
        {
            if (request == null)
            {
                request = new OrderByRequest
                {
                    IsAscending = true,
                    PropertyName = "Name"  // CreatedDate , LevelNo etc
                };
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.PropertyName))
            {
                request.PropertyName = "Name";
            }
            Tuple<Expression, Type> selector = GetSelector(new List<string>() {request.PropertyName});
            Type type = selector.Item2;
            Type[] argumentTypes = new[] { typeof(Level), type };

            var orderByMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
                .First(method => method.Name == "OrderBy"
                    && method.GetParameters().Count() == 2)
                    .MakeGenericMethod(argumentTypes);
            var orderByDescMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
                .First(method => method.Name == "OrderByDescending"
                    && method.GetParameters().Count() == 2)
                    .MakeGenericMethod(argumentTypes);

            if (request.IsAscending)
                return query => (IOrderedQueryable<Level>)
                    orderByMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {query, selector.Item1});
            else
                return query => (IOrderedQueryable<Level>)
                    orderByDescMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {query, selector.Item1});
        }

        private static Tuple<Expression, Type> GetSelector(IEnumerable<string> propertyNames)
        {
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Level));
            Expression body = parameter;

            foreach (var property in propertyNames)
            {
                body = Expression.Property(body,
                    body.Type.GetProperty(property));
            }

            return Tuple.Create(Expression.Lambda(body, parameter) as Expression
                , body.Type);
        }
```