# C# OrderBy Function with a dynamic return value type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sorting

I am using Entity Framework and would like to order the response of a query but the orderable property is decided by the user. I'd also like the entire query to be run in SQL. I tried using reflection to determine the orderable column but EF seems to run that part of the query in memory, stripping off any of my where clauses. Currently I just have a set of switch statemtns (one for OrderBY and one for OrderByDescending) but that's pretty ham fisted and not the best for maintainability.

## Objects

```
public class Human {
      public Guid Id { get; set; }
      public int Weight { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
}

public enum SortOn {
      Id,
      Weight,
      Name
}
```

## Use Case

The idea here is that the method would use a passed in SortOn variable to determine what property to sort on. Currently this is what that looks like.

```
switch (sortOn) {
      case SortOn.Id:
          query = query.OrderBy(q => q.Id);
          break;
      case SortOn.Weight:
          query = query.OrderBy(q => q.Weight);
          break;
      case SortOn.Name:
          query = query.OrderBy(q => q.Name);
          break;
}
```

this switch statement would have to be wrapped in an if/else to determine if the sorting is ascending or descending. Obviously this is not particularly elegant or maintainable.

## The Question

I'd like to be able to just pass a method to the OrderBy that would result in the property to order on. This would simplify things as my method could just determine order direction while another method would determine the property to sort on meaning I'd only have 1 block of code to update on property changes. However, I cannot figure out a way to pass a function into the OrderBy call. I think the reason is that I have a Guid, int and string meaning I'd have to have overloads for each type. If that's the case I'd actually be creating more code to maintain and this exercise is meaningless. So the question is, how do you pass in a method to an OrderBy statement if the return type is unknown as compile time?

Comment: You want anything like `OrderBy(q => q["MyProperty"])`? In this case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet is your duplicate.

Comment: One of many possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2728340/861716, or https://stackoverflow.com/q/41244/861716

Comment: The problem is, that as you already mentioned, all possible methods have different signatures: while `q.id` returns a Guid, `q.Weight` returns a number. So the actual return-type of the method is unknown at compile-time. However `OrderBy` expects a delegate expecting an instance of `T` known at *compile*-time.

Comment: If you have many different objects that are going to have this problem, then have the queryable objects themselves tell you what columns are sortable and provide a method for providing a method that will type match your orderby.  Or, just use a big if statement.  Sometimes simple is best.  :)

Comment: I ended up using Dyanmic Linq to solve this issue. Thank you very much.