# C# OrderBy with LINQ expression or string variable

Tags: c#, linq

I need to order my items by a variable from users request. The request gives me a string with field name. There can be over 40 fields so anything like switch / case is not acceptable. I need something like `item.OrderBy(x => myString)`

Is that possible?

Comment: this has already been answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728340/how-can-i-do-an-orderby-with-a-dynamic-string-parameter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do an OrderBy with a dynamic string parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728340/how-can-i-do-an-orderby-with-a-dynamic-string-parameter)

Comment: Another similar existing: [Dynamic LINQ `OrderBy` on `IEnumerable<T>` / `IQueryable<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/233505/23354)

Comment: What kind of sorting of the elements? by val asc?

Comment: But with all of those answers I would need to make a helper class with LINQ to string ex. x=>x.field = string1 and I must avoid this

Comment: @San not sure what you're trying to say there, but I wrote at least one of those answers, and it would work fine as `var ordered = source.OrderBy(myString);`, where `myString` is the member name