# Trying to pass order by clause as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I was trying to pass `orderby` clause as a parameter:

```
public IList<SomeType> GetData(Expression<Func<Customer, object>> order)
{
        if (order==null)
        {
            order =   x => x.PrintOrder ;
        }

        var list = (from c in this.dbContext.Customer
                    where c.Type==1
                    orderby order
                    select new {c.Name }).ToList();

        return list;
}
```

But this throws an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: could not be translated.
> Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList'

Comment: Is it possible to add multiple fields to order parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public IList<Customer> GetData(Expression<Func<Customer, object>> order = null)
    {

    order ??= x => x.PrintOrder;

    //var list = (from c in this.dbContext.Customer
    //             where c.Type==1
    //          orderby order
    //          select c).ToList();
    
    //may works
    return  this.dbContext.Customer.Where(c => c.Type == 1)
                                   .OrderBy(order)
                                   .ToList();
    }
```

Comment: as you can see in my question i have not used extension methods. just i am trying with out extension method. since both approaches are same, just i was wondering why that is not working, and  if i modify code   if (order==null)
            {
                order=   x => new { x.PrintOrder,x.Sfix } ;
            }  like this, above code also fails to translate

Comment: @AvinashNG You *have* to use method syntax to be able to pass an expression into the query. This answer is correct. You didn't mention the other ordering in your question.

Comment: @GertArnold, Yes if you use extension method the above answer is right. as you can see i have tried different approach.

Comment: Since `order` is an optional input parameter, would it work if it is null without giving it any default expression?

Answer (score -1):

**Update**:
As suggested in the comments, this method is only suitable for LINQ-to-object situations, if connecting to DB use accepted answear instead

**Original answear**:

This works:

```
Func<Customer, object> order = (c) => c.PrintOrder;
var list = (from c in this.dbContext.Customer
        orderby order(c)
        select c).ToList();
```

The difference is in calling the function order(c), instead of just passing it

You could also use this syntax:

```
Func<Customer, object> order = (c) => c.PrintOrder;
var list = this.dbContext.Customer.OrderBy(order).ToList();
```

Take a look at this post: [How can I do an OrderBy with a dynamic string parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728340/how-can-i-do-an-orderby-with-a-dynamic-string-parameter)

Comment: your first solution is throws the same exception as i asked in my question. Second is similar to the accepted answer.

Comment: Also, using `Func<Customer, object>` is a serious mistake when applying it to `IQueryable`.

Comment: That's odd, I just tested this in linqpad and it worked (I replaced the source with normal list).

Comment: So test it in the same circumstances as the question. This is not LINQ to objects.

Comment: I based my answer on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10413311/12417800